# Как отменить запрос AngularJS Resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request, promise

Есть Resource, который получает информацию об объекте. Информации много и в зависимости, от выбранного объекта она может рассчитываться достаточно долго.

```
$scope.currentInfo = null;
Info = $resource('/info');

$scope.getInfo = function(id) {
   Info.post({id: id}).$promise.then(function(response) {
      $scope.currentInfo = response.data;
   })
}
```

В какой то момент, пользователь может запросить информацию о другом объекте, не дождавшись ответа на первы запрос.
Как в таком случае отменить первый запрос, что бы он не перезаписал *$scope.currentInfo*, если ответ на него придет позже, чем на второй запрос?

Comment: Try https://developer.rackspace.com/blog/cancelling-ajax-requests-in-angularjs-applications/

Comment: Посмотрите на этот вопрос http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666960/how-to-cancel-resource-requests. Думаю, второй ответ вам подойдет.

Comment: Посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource). Там есть функция `$cancelRequest`.

Comment: $cancelRequest то что нужно! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [документации](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource), запрос можно отменить с помощью функции `$cancelRequest`. Для этого необходимо в метод добавить опцию `cancellable`.

Данный параметр работает для версии, начиная с **1.5.0**.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/9dcdqx68/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngResource'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function(ExampleService) {
    var vm = this;
    //Массив для отображения информации о запросах
    vm.request = [];
    vm.start = function() {
      vm.cancel(); //Отменяем предыдущий запрос
      ExampleService.getData(1).$promise
        .then(function() {
          console.log('success');
        })
        .catch(function(data) {
          console.log('catch', data);
          vm.request.push(data);
        });
    };
    vm.cancel = function() {
      if (ExampleService.getData.$promise)
        ExampleService.getData.$promise.$cancelRequest();
    };
  })
  .service('ExampleService', function($resource) {
    var Example = $resource("/data/:id", {
      id: "@id"
    }, {
      // Let's make the `query()` method cancellable
      query: {
        method: 'get',
        isArray: true,
        cancellable: true
      }
    });
    return {
      getData: function(id) {
        // Сохраняем промис для отмены
        this.getData.$promise = Example.query({
          id: id
        });
        return this.getData.$promise;
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-resource.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.start()">
      Start Request
    </button>
    <button ng-click="vm.cancel()">
      Cancel Request
    </button>
    <div ng-repeat="req in vm.request">
      <pre>{{$index}}: status = {{req.status}} statusText = {{req.status==-1?"Cancelled":req.statusText}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

К сожалению, сниппет не работает. Но код рабочий и jsfiddle тоже.

Answer (score 0):

При использовании сервиса $http, например $http.get('urltoresource', {timeout: myPromise}) параметр timeout принимает промис, если его зарезолвить, то запрос будет прерван. Это на всякий случай, если не будет аналога с resource. Создать промис можно с помощью сервиса $q